# Java отправка string переменных по JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

есть переменная

```
String ip = Getip.getip();
```

есть запрос на добавление данных в mysql

```
String[] insert = {"INSERT INTO users(ip) VALUES ( ip );"}; //
```

но почему-то ip в запросе не распознается как переменная которую я указал выше. Эклипс предлагает ее удалить, т.к не используется не где. что не правильно тут?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java не делает подстановки переменных в строке, для неё `ip` - это всего лишь две буквы строки. Желаемого вами можно добиться так:

```
String[] insert = {"INSERT INTO users(ip) VALUES ( " + ip + " );"};
```

Но лучше используйте [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users(ip) VALUES ( ? );"
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
preparedStatement.setString(1, ip);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Это и проще, и убережёт от ошибок, а самое главное - это безопаснее, защитит от [SQL injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Comment: Разобрался со вторым вариантом! Спасибо большое помогло